# Upgrade shimano tiagra mechanical disc to tiagra hydraulic disc brakes

Tags: hydraulic-disc-brake, upgrades, mechanical

I currently have a Scott Speedster 20 with Tiarga 10 speed mechanical disc brakes. Is it possible to upgrade my brakes with the hydraulic version of the tiagra groupsset (by just buying these parts e.g. https://www.bike24.com/p2327120.html).

Or is it not as simple as switching these parts out and would for example the cables for switching gears fit into the new levers?

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new shifters and brake calipers you link to should come with new gear cables in the box. If they don’t, it will make your life easier to thread new gear inners through the new shifters rather than trying to reuse the old ones, which tend to lose strands at the end and can become stuck.

You have correctly identified you don’t need anything else. Make sure the new callipers will fit your frame (i.e. flat mount calipers needs flat mount frame; post mount calipers need correct adaptors.